# Как получить элемент из многомерного массива?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Я использую **framewokr Yii2**. Как можно получить значение элементов из этого массива, если не ошибаюсь, это многомерный ассоциативный массив.

Как например получить значение ключа **'label'**?

```
[
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
            Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
                ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
                [
                    'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                    'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
                ],
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: `$array['items'][$i]['label']` - а так не берется?

Comment: @splash58 Во! Cупер, спасибо!

Comment: @splash58  Так этот массив не просто ассоциативный, в нем еще и индексный массив есть оОО.... А как такие массивы называются, смешанные?

Comment: не знаю, называются ли они как-то, в php массив всегда страшная структура :)